# Debugging my Android phone through ADB gets me: < was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows-7, android, debug

I want to send commands to my Xiaomi Redmi Note 4G through Android Debug Bridge, but every time I write a command such as:

```
adb -s<3729749> <reboot-bootloader>
```

I get a response:

```
< was unexpected at this time
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Is your phone in debugging mode?

Comment: yes I turned on USB debugging and I saw my phone in the device list

Comment: what if you type just `adb<ENTER>`  how about `adb shell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adb -s<3729749> <reboot-bootloader>
< was unexpected at this time
```

Just like it says: you should not specify the `<`.

When the help says:

```
adb --help
...
-s <serial number>
    - directs command to the USB device or emulator with
      the given serial number. Overrides ANDROID_SERIAL
      environment variable.
```

...that means you have to specify the serial number, without the `<...>`.

Optional parameters are enclosed in square brackets, `[...]`. For, for example:

```
connect <host>[:<port>]
    - connect to a device via TCP/IP
      Port 5555 is used by default if no port number is specified.
```

...you'd use something like:

```
connect 192.168.1.1
connect 192.168.1.1:5555 (same as above)
connect 10.0.0.1:123
```

And for:

```
adb reboot [bootloader|recovery]
    - reboots the device, optionally into the bootloader or recovery program
adb reboot-bootloader
    - reboots the device into the bootloader
```

...you'd optionally specify one of the given options `bootloader` or `recovery` to run the first command. So your full command should be one of:

```
adb -s 3729749 reboot bootloader
adb -s 3729749 reboot-bootloader
```

Comment: Thank you so much Arjan. I have understood and tried what you told me and it worked.Thanks once again

Comment: okay Arjan....am kinda  new in this